# Convexity of 3D curve?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, differential-topology, 3d, curves

For convexity of a curve, I only find a definition restricted to the case where the curve lies in a plane. Is there definition for the convexity of a curve in the three-dimensional space?

Comment: What does it mean for a curve to be convex?

Comment: One definition is that a curve is convex if it lies on the boundary of its convex hull.  This definition makes sense in $R^n$. There is also a notion of "hyperconvex curve".

Comment: @MoisheCohen "One definition is that a curve is convex if it lies on the boundary of its convex hull" - can you show me the reference?